# Using a linq or lambda expression in C# return a collection plus a single value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'd like to return a collection plus a single value. Presently I am using a field to create a new list adding a value to the list and then returning the result. Is there a way to do this with a linq or lambda expression?

```
private List<ChargeDetail> _chargeBreakdown
    = new List<ChargeDetail>();

public ChargeDetail PrimaryChargeDetail { get; set; }

public List<ChargeDetail> ChargeBreakdown
{
    get
    {
        List<ChargeDetail> result =
            new List<ChargeDetail>(_chargeBreakdown);
        result.Add(PrimaryChargeDetail);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to return a collection other than `List<T>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Reed added the _chareBreakdown field

Comment: @Russ thank you for the suggestion, I won't for the production code. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax instead:

```
public List<ChargeDetail> ChargeBreakdown
{
    get
    {
        return new List<ChargeDetail>(_chargeBreakdown) {PrimaryChargeDetail};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the property type to `IEnumerable<ChargeDetail>` you could do:

```
public IEnumerable<ChargeDetail> ChareBreakdown
{
    get { return _chargeBreakdown.Concat(new[] { PrimaryChargeDetail }); }
}
```

Which could be simpler depending on how clients use the class (for example if they just iterate through the collection). They could always call `ToList` if they need to manipulate a list.